# Query Actual Execution Plan VERY different from Trace results

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have rebuilt indexes and updated statistics.

The query is straightforward, with a subquery in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * from MeetingPost_reg
WHERE userid = 1234 AND meetingpost_regid <> 9999 
AND DateStart < (SELECT DateStart FROM MeetingPost_reg WHERE meetingpost_regid = 9999)
ORDER BY DateStart desc
```

There is an index on datastart, userid.
meetingpost_regid is the PK, with clustered index.

**SHOWPLAN_TEXT:**

```
StmtText                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([MeetingPost_reg].[message]=[MeetingPost_reg].[message], [MeetingPost_reg].[ProcessedComment]=[MeetingPost_reg].[ProcessedComment], [MeetingPost_reg].[ProcessedMsg]=[MeetingPost_reg].[ProcessedMsg], [MeetingPost_reg].[pos_discou
       |--Top(1)
            |--Bookmark Lookup(BOOKMARK:([Bmk1000]), OBJECT:([dbo].[MeetingPost_reg]))
                 |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MeetingPost_reg].[datestart]))
                      |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([dbo].[MeetingPost_reg].[PK_MeetingPost_reg]), SEEK:([MeetingPost_reg].[meetingpost_regid]=9999) ORDERED FORWARD)
                      |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([dbo].[MeetingPost_reg].[MeetingPost_reg12]), SEEK:([MeetingPost_reg].[datestart] < [MeetingPost_reg].[datestart]),  WHERE:([MeetingPost_reg].[meetingpost_regid]<>9999 AND Convert([MeetingPost_reg

(6 row(s) affected)
```

**Execution Plan:**

The Execution Plan diagram shows an Index Seek with 0 rows, and a Clustered Index Seek with 1 row, for a total Cost of ~ .0006, total CPU Cost ~ .002

The Trace shows a Duration of 250, CPU 172, Reads 11.  The Trace Event Class is **SQL:StmtCompleted**

Why is this query using so much CPU?

Answer (score 2):

Profiler event shows 172ms worker time and 250ms elapsed time, 11 page reads. Is that for the [SQL:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189886.aspx) or for the [SQL:BatchCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176010.aspx) event? If later, is this query the only statement in the batch?

For the execution plan, you better post the actual plan, reducing an entire plan to 2 operators and 4 numbers (0, 1, .0006 and .002) looses quite a lot from the plan information.

Does the captured plan and the statement execution refer to *exactly* the same execution? If yes, have you considered that the cost of returning the plan is included in the trace event?

Comment: Yes it is the exact same execution, run in the Profiler.
I don't think it is the cost of the plan, since the query is similarly heavy *in vivo*